$x \mapsto \delta_x$ is a continuous function
Let $f: J \times I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function where J is a compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and I is an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Given $x \in J$, let
$$f_x: I \to \mathbb{R} \, ; \, y \mapsto f(x,y).$$
For all $y_0 \in I$ we have $f_x$ continuous in $y_0$ so for the $\epsilon$ given we have $\delta_x > 0$ such that for all $y \in (y_0 - \delta_x, y_0 + \delta_x)$ implies $|f_x(y) - f_x(y_0)| < \epsilon$.
So, by the Axiom of Choice, we can define a function from J to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x \mapsto \delta_x$.
My question is, we can define such function in a continuous way, using the hypothesis that J is compact and f is continuous?
Thanks.

Your definition of $\delta_x$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and $y_0$. Why don't you indicate that dependence in your notation by writing $\delta_{x,\varepsilon,y_0}$?  This would make it clearer that what you call $\delta_x$ is not purely a function of $x$ alone by the way you are defining $\delta_x$.

@KCd Can I fix $\epsilon$ and $y_0$, so I can analyze the $\delta$ being a function of x alone?

Do whatever you want, although by keeping $y_0$ unchanged you might as well let $f$ be a single-variable function on  a compact interval $J$. Then by uniform continuity of continuous functions on compact intervals, $\delta_x$ can be made the same value for all $x \in J$, so it can be chosen to be a constant function and then your question is not interesting.
